# How do I get back the old Ubuntu settings interface?

Tags: system-settings

When I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 (not LTS) I noticed there was a new settings program called "Settings" The old settings app was called "System Settings".

How would I get the old settings program back?

Comment: Close voters. Answered.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you properly you are looking for the one that was referred to as "System Settings" in the GUI which is actually [unity-control-center](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=unity-control-center) which is still available for all supported versions of Ubuntu, although for supported versions higher than 16.04 you have to [enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) in order to install it.

Comment: The reason 17.10 doesn't have unity-control-centre is presumably that it doesn't use Unity? That seems important to note... I am not at all au fait with either DE...

Comment: @Zanna I can see how one might presume that based on the naming convention but while  unity-control-center has a long list of dependencies, unity (which is also [available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unity&searchon=names) for all supported versions of Ubuntu is not a requirement. Even the unity package *recommends* unity-control-center it but doesn't list it as a requirement.

Comment: Oh... it even says on your packages link "utilities to configure the GNOME desktop" o.O weird naming convention indeed...

Comment: @Zanna Proof positive that you can't judge a book (or package) by it's title. ;-)